# JSONException while attempting to retrieve data from database

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database. I send a request to this PHP file:

```
<?php

    require "init.php";

    $qrcode = $_POST["qrcode"];

    $sql = "select * from cespite where QrCode = $qrcode;";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
    {
        $code = "reg_failed";
        $message = "Nessun risultato trovato!";

        $err = array("code"=>$code, "message"=>$message);
        echo json_encode($err);
    }
    else
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)[0];
        echo json_encode($row);
    }

    //$mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This is the code where I send the request to that file:

```
final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                try
                {
                    Nome.setText(response.getString("Nome"));
                    Descrizione.setText(response.getString("Descrizione"));
                    Numinventario.setText(response.getString("NumInventario"));
                    Foto.setText(response.getString("Foto"));
                    Dtcatalogazione.setText(response.getString("DtCatalogazione"));
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                int j = 21;
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(1);
                params.put("qrcode", richiesta);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RegisterRequest.getmInstance(this).addToRequestque(request);
```

This is my `RegisterRequest` class:

```
public class RegisterRequest
{
    private static RegisterRequest mInstance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;
    //default constructor
    private RegisterRequest(Context context)
    {
        mCtx=context;
        requestQueue=getRequestQueue();
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
    {
        if(requestQueue==null)
        {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx);
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public static synchronized RegisterRequest getmInstance(Context context)
    {
        if(mInstance==null)
        {
            mInstance = new RegisterRequest(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void addToRequestque(Request request)
    {
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

}
```

I've tried with my debugger. I always finish in the `onErrorResponse` method and I can't figure out why, because I've tried to send a request to my PHP file from web and it works correctly, so I think it could be a problem of sending the params to the request.
The error I get is `Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: solved making a string request instead of jsonobject request

Comment: I think that you are requestion wrong URL.

Comment: @VladMatvienko nope, it's correct -_-'

Comment: Check the response using PostMan

Comment: the error says that you get HTML in response instead of JSON, so I still think that it is incorrect. Or you didn't put your PHP file in correct place. Or the PHP is incorrect. First check through the browser, or any other HTTP util, that you will get JSON in response.

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred in your PHP script, which caused the output to be something like this:

```
ERROR AT LINE X: INFORMATION ABOUT THE ERROR

{"code": "code", "message": "Something went wrong"}
```

This causes the overall output to be invalid JSON (since the first ERROR-line is not JSON). This causes the JSON exception you are receiving. Try to verify if your PHP script is working by for example contacting it with a standard text-request instead of a JSONRequest. This way you should see the PHP error that occurred. You can also try looking in your server logs to see if there's anything useful there.

Another remark, your PHP script is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Try to see what happens if you replace the value of `$_POST['qrcode']` with a quote (for example: ' ). This way someone having malicious intents can get his hands on your entire database. You can fix this using prepared statements.

Comment: I've already tried my php with a simple text request and it works; I can't figure out why with a Json request it doesn't work

Comment: @Interseba5 oh I see your problem, your json contains "alldata": [{"Nome": .... }] but in your java you are assuming it only contains {"Nome": .... }

Answer (score 0):

try to make proper jsonObject

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
{

$array = array();

$array[] = "reg_failed";
$array[] = "reg_failed";"Nessun risultato trovato!";

$get = array("error" => $array);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($get);
}else{

$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$array[] = $row;
}
$get = array("alldata" => $array);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($get);

}
```

here is java code to parse the jsonObject

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("alldata");

JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

if (jsonObj.getString("Nome") != null) {

Nome.setText(jsonObj.getString("Nome"));
Descrizione.setText(jsonObj.getString("Descrizione")); 
Numinventario.setText(jsonObj.getString("NumInventario"));
Foto.setText(jsonObj.getString("Foto"));
Dtcatalogazione.setText(jsonObj.getString("DtCatalogazione"));
}
```

let me know if you have still issues

Comment: No man same issue..

Look the php output:
http://imgur.com/L2O1qVj

Error in Android Studio:
http://imgur.com/D0PuHy4

Comment: now you are parsing jsonObject in wrong way. show me the parsing code you are using in android Studio

Comment: Here's the request class:
http://imgur.com/cFhBtx2

ShowData activity(where I send request):
http://imgur.com/4ma9OP7

http://imgur.com/L0qtSqO

Comment: there is issue with your parsing code. let me update the answer.

Comment: Solved making a string request instead of a jsonobject request, thanks anyway!